# ConcurrentHashMap in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I need to use the same `HashMap` from different threads *(EDT, a Timer, and maybe the Network Thread)*. Since Codename One doesn't have a `ConcurrentHashMap` implementation in its API, I tried to circumvent this issue so:

```
/**
 * ConcurrentHashMap emulation for Codename One.
 */
public class ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> {

    private static final EasyThread thread = EasyThread.start("concurrentHashMap_Thread");
    private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return thread.run(() -> map.put(key, value));
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return thread.run(() -> map.get(key));
    }

    public V remove(K key) {
        return thread.run(() -> map.remove(key));
    }

}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is a code like the above actually necessary in Codename One, when accessing a `Map` from two or more threads? Is it better to use an `HashMap` directly?
2. What do you think about that code? I tried to keep it as simple as possible, but I'm not sure of its correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is very correct. It's also very inefficient as you're creating multiple locks to add a new object to a different thread. So you're effectively bringing a tank to a problem that's far simpler.

The TL;DR is this:

```
map = Collections.synchronizedMap(map);
```

Your code could have been written like this and would have been more efficient:

```
public class ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> {
    private static final EasyThread thread = EasyThread.start("concurrentHashMap_Thread");
    private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {
        return map.put(key, value);
    }

    public synchronized V get(K key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public synchronized V remove(K key) {
        return map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

But you obviously don't need it since we have the `synchronizedMap` method...

So why don't we have `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Because we don't run on huge servers. See this article: https://crunchify.com/hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap-vs-synchronizedmap-how-a-hashmap-can-be-synchronized-in-java/

The TL;DR of that article is that `ConcurrentHashMap` makes sense when you have a lot of threads and a lot of server cores. It tries to go the extra mile at limiting synchronization for maximum scale. In mobile that's a huge overkill.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and clear explanation :)